# How do you find the adjoint of a function?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is there a formula to find the adjoint of a function?  For instance I have $T(\alpha)=(x+iy)\alpha$, how would I compute $T^*(\alpha)$?

Answer (score 1):

You want $\langle T\alpha, \beta\rangle=\langle \alpha, T^*\beta\rangle$. Here the left-hand side is $(x+iy)\langle \alpha,\beta\rangle$, so in this example $T^*\alpha=(x-iy)\alpha$.